# Push notification using fcm in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on react native push notification sample example . 
i am getting error to build the app .

Error is ...

```
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: E:\REACT-NATIVE\fcmreactnative\android\app\google-services.json
:app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Failed to delete: E:\REACT-NATIVE\fcmreactnative\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug
```

I am using android build.gradle with version

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

and android/app/build.gradle

dependencies {
     compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}
```

please help me how to resolve it..

Comment: Did you run react-native link?

Comment: yes , i run it .

Comment: Ok then make sure you modified all the required files, follow this guideline https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm#android-configuration

Answer (score 0):

in [firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/) console,you can:

```
for Android: download google-services.json file and place it in android/app directory
for iOS: download GoogleService-Info.plist file and place it in /ios/your-project-name directory (next to your Info.plist)
```

Make sure you have certificates setup by following https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Comment: I had dowloaded google-services.json file added it in android/app/dir.Stil getting same error.

Comment: It is successfull